# Where can one learn Chandas through english?

Tags: vedanga, reference-request

***Chandas*** is one of the limbs in the study of Vedas (*Vedangas*). It is the study of Vedic verses with emphasis on poetic meters.

- What are the best introductory resources for the study of Chandas available in english?
- Are there any modern works that explain the construction and use of these Vedic meters using english verses and examples?

Answer (score 2):

The book [Chandas as Vedanga](https://ebooks.tirumala.org/read?id=7&title=Chandas%20as%20Vedanga) , hosted by Tirumala Tirupathi , could be an excellent introductory resource for the study of Chandas in English.
This book is available for free download from TTD's(ebooks) website .

> The book ‘Chandas as Vedanga’ written by
> Dr. Madhavi R. Narsalay explains all the basic
> principles of Vedic prosody which is necessary to gain
> knowledge about metres before learning Veda. The
> effort put by the author is priceless. Hope that this
> treatise will enhance the desirers to learn more about
> Vedas and Vedangas.
> *In the Service of Lord Venkateswara*

Regarding question 2 , Not sure if anyone had ever tried , to use Vedic metres on English verses. In my opinion, it is needless, and may not be an appropriate endeavour .

Comment: almost all poems in hindi are written in sanskrit chhanda, don't know if that can be an answer to the second question

Comment: while reciting any  mantra, (sahasranama etc). Rishi , Chandas and Devata is imperative .This seems to be relatable to Hindi bhajans as well. But ,I'm nt sure how  is it adaptable to an English verse,(though they may have their own prosody logistics).

Comment: not bhajans but poems in general was meant there

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmozlYyYE-ERI52EVhtqsdpTUBKf7IoAd) youtube video is an excellent introduction to Classical Sanskrit Chandas.